# How to do unit testing of ViewData in razor pages?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Having the following *reduced* code (.net core 3.1):

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
{
    ViewData["ACustomMessage"] = $"This a custom message";

    return Page();
}
```

I need a unit test where I can test the message created in ViewData.

```
public void Test_ViewData()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<PrivacyModel>>();
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext)
    {
        ViewData = viewData
    };
    PrivacyModel privacyRazorPage = new PrivacyModel(loggerMock.Object)
    {
        PageContext = pageContext,
        TempData = tempData,
        Url = new UrlHelper(actionContext)
    };

    var resultPrivacy = privacyRazorPage.OnGet();

    Assert.AreEqual("This a custom message", ((PageResult)resultPrivacy).ViewData["ACustomMessage"]);
}
```

This test does not work because `resultPrivacy` is returned as an instantiated object but with all its properties as null.

[image: ViewData returned as null]

Comment: the framework is what passes the values to the result at runtime. But since this is an isolated unit test that wont happen automatically. You will need to check the view data of the page model and inspect it there.

Answer (score 1):

You need change the following code:

```
Assert.AreEqual("This a custom message", ((PageResult)resultPrivacy).ViewData["ACustomMessage"]);
```

To:

```
Assert.AreEqual("This a custom message", privacyRazorPage.ViewData["ACustomMessage"]);
```

Whole working demo:

```
public void Test_ViewData()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<PrivacyModel>>();
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext)
    {
        ViewData = viewData
    };
    PrivacyModel privacyRazorPage = new PrivacyModel(loggerMock.Object)
    {
        PageContext = pageContext,
        TempData = tempData,
        Url = new UrlHelper(actionContext)
    };
    privacyRazorPage.OnGet();
    Assert.AreEqual("This a custom message", privacyRazorPage.ViewData["ACustomMessage"]);
}
```